# Does event capturing go through siblings of the firing node?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, event-capturing

Say we have:

```
<div id="parent">d1
  <div id="child-1">child-1</div>
  <div id="child-2">child-2</div>
</div>
```

I have an event listener on `child-2`.

From what I understand, event capturing will go down the node tree until it reaches the node the event fired.

Does event capturing also go through the sibling children, checking if they are the target that fired the event?

Comment: Have a look at [capturing and bubbling](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-event-propagation.php)

Comment: @ATD I've looked at it, didn't found something that addresses how capturing treat siblings. maybe I missed, or I'm suppose to look for something else?

Comment: The document shows that capturing and bubbling go up and down between the event trigger element and the top node.  It also explains that, if the event trigger element contains nodes itself, the capturing goes **down** to those as well.  It doesn't go up one level and then down to all child nodes.  Thus, in your example, if the "parent" div was the trigger, it would go down to both "child-1" and "child-2" but it doesn't go "child-1", "parent", "child-2".

Comment: Look at it like: ....grandparent.parent.**trigger**.children.grandchildren....  There will be a **direct** path from one object to another **through** the trigger element.  The element identifies itself as the triggering element, so there is no need for any code to check for that.

Comment: @ATD so the element that fires the event, holds the information of the path the capturing goes through?
If so then it make, sense.

Comment: Not at such.  The element that triggers the event, just says "I triggered the event".  From that, the capturing and bubbling mechanisms work out the paths and checks if events need to be triggered on other elements as well - if they do, a new event is triggered and the triggering element is that one, not the original one.

Comment: @ATD what does "mechanisms work out the paths" mean? from this I understand that the path is not known, meaning capturing goes through the siblings of the node that fires the event in order to know who fired.

Comment: Why would capturing go through the siblings, where have you got that idea from?  Consider this scenario:  Add an event listener for the click event on the body tag.  Does the event listener need to know ALL of the elements within the body tag at ALL times?  No, of course not, it would be a waste to keep that up to date as elements can be added, deleted or modified at any time. When the trigger is fired by someone clicking the body tag, **then** it works out what the elements are and my `...parent.**trigger**.children...` example shows that siblings are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in this snippet if click on child1 first parent then  child1 fires.
if you check the console you'll see that both `e.target` are the same, so the event will target the same element on parent and child.
when clicking the child1 : event goes from parent to child1 and child2 event never fire up

```js
const parent= document.getElementById('parent');

const child1 = document.getElementById('child1');
const child2 = document.getElementById('child2');

parent.addEventListener(
  'click',
  e => {
  console.log("parent")
  console.log(e.target)
  },
  true
);

child1.addEventListener(
  'click',
  e => {
    console.log("child1")
    console.log(e.target);
  },
  true
);

child2.addEventListener(
  'click',
  e => {
    console.log("child2")
    console.log(e.target);
  },
  true
);
```

```css
.parent{
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
background-color: orange;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Expense Tracker</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Event Capturing</h1>
    <div class="parent" id="parent">
      <h2 id="child1">Child1</h2>
      <h3 id="child2">Child2</h3>
    
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```